# How do I generate an error or warning in the C preprocessor?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I have a program that must be compiled only in DEBUG mode. (testing purpose)

How can I have the preprocessor prevent compilation in RELEASE mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create custom #warning flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168245/create-custom-warning-flags)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Place anywhere:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#error "Only Debug builds are supported"
#endif
```

For reference: [Diagnostics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html#Diagnostics)

Comment: I've started using NDEBUG instead of DEBUG. That way, if NDEBUG isn't defined, compilation defaults to debug mode, so `#ifdef NDEBUG` instead of `#ifndef DEBUG`.

Answer (score 27):

C provide a `#error` statement, and most compilers add a `#warning` statement. [The gcc documentation recommends](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/cpp/Diagnostics.html) to quote the message.

Comment: @Antonio Right, there is no [more] recommendation there. I replaced the link with one to gcc doc.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe something more sofisticated, but it is only copy&paste of previous solutions. :-)

```
#ifdef DEBUG        
    #pragma message ( "Debug configuration - OK" )
#elif RELEASE   
    #error "Release configuration - WRONG"
#else
    #error "Unknown configuration - DEFINITELY WRONG"
#endif
```

P.S. There is also another way how to generate a warning.
Create an unreferenced label like

```
HereIsMyWarning:
```

and don't reference it. During compilation, you will get a warning like

```
 1>..\Example.c(71) : warning C4102: 'HereIsMyWarning' : unreferenced label
```

Comment: `#pragma message ( "Debug configuration - OK" )` works (only) for MSVC, while `#warning "..."` doesn't work for MSVC, but works for gcc and clang.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `error` directive for that. The following code will throw an error at compile time if `DEBUG` is not defined:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#error This is an error message
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry, I mix pragma and error while typing. Corrected in answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to report an error:

```
#ifdef RELEASE
  #error Release mode not allowed
#endif
```

will work with most compilers.

Answer (score 3):

For GCC and Clang (and probably any compiler that supports the _Pragma feature) you can define a macro:

```
#if ! DEBUG
#define FIX_FOR_RELEASE(statement) _Pragma ("GCC error \"Must be fixed for release version\"")
#else
#define FIX_FOR_RELEASE(statement) statement
#endif
```

You can use this macro for temporary hacks, for example to get around code that a co-worker hasn't written yet, to make sure you don't forget to fix it once you want to release a build to the public. Either

```
FIX_FOR_RELEASE()
// Code that must be removed or fixed before you can release
```

or

```
FIX_FOR_RELEASE(statement that must be removed or fixed before you can release);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Code::Blocks, if you don't want the Release mode, you can delete the Release mode. To do this, click on the Project menu, select Properties..., and in the Build targets tab you can click on Release and then click on the Delete button. Deleting the Release mode only does it for the current project, so you can still use it in other projects.

Otherwise, if you really want to use the preprocessor, you can do this:

```
#ifdef RELEASE
#error "You have to use the Debug mode"
#endif
```