# Compiler should raise an error for certain combinations of #define

Tags: c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

In a current project, I'm experimenting around a lot to see the performance influence of different solutions. Since I like to keep all the code, I have a lot of #ifdef directives, which make it easy for me to switch on and off some optimizations. However, some combinations of defines are not covered. I'd like to see a compiler error if this happens, i.e.:

```
#define A
#define B

#ifdef A
#ifdef B
//invalid combination of defines. Compiler should raise an error.
#endif
#endif

#ifdef A
//do something
#endif
#ifdef B
//do something else
#endif
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Just use the [error directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221517/how-to-generate-an-error-and-warning-in-c-preprocessor) (`#error`).

```
#ifdef A
#ifdef B
#error "invalid combination of defines."
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Edit: Sorry, seems you edited your post while I figured that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifdef A
#ifdef B
//invalid combination of defines. Compiler should raise an error.
#error Invalid combination
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the error Preprocessor directive:

```
#error "Invalid combination"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#if defined(A) && defined(B)
#error invalid combination of defines
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for hte hint with defined!