# With C++11, how can I generate a warning message in a manner that works in gcc, clang, and MSVC?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, clang

When compiling C++11 using clang or gcc, I can generate a warning message at compilation time using:

```
#warning My message here
```

This doesn't work on Windows when I use MSVC, though. How can I intentionally generate a warning message that will work regardless of C++ compiler?

This question is not a duplicate of ["preprocessor #warning equivalent in Visual C++?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694305/preprocessor-warning-equivalent-in-visual-c) because that question is not attempting to answer the question of how do it in a way that works across compilers.

Comment: Also look at [`std::static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) for hard errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703528/what-code-have-you-written-with-pragma-you-found-useful/2706693#2706693) as a starting point, I found a method that works in gcc, clang, and MSVC. The following precompiler magic will do the trick:

```
#define EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_STRINGIFY0(x) #x
#define EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_STRINGIFY1(x) EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_STRINGIFY0(x)
#ifdef __GNUC__
    #define EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_COMPOSE(x) GCC warning x
#else
    #define EMIT_COMPILER_MESSAGE_PREFACE(type) \
    __FILE__ "(" EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_STRINGIFY1(__LINE__) "): " type ": "
    #define EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_COMPOSE(x) message(EMIT_COMPILER_MESSAGE_PREFACE("warning C0000") x)
#endif
#define WARNING(x) _Pragma(EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_STRINGIFY1(EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_COMPOSE(x)))
```

You can trigger a warning with:

```
WARNING("This is a warning message.")
```

In the case of MSVC, it displays a compiler message in the same format that the compiler would for a warning message, which causes it to be detected as a warning. (The use of `C0000` is simply to stick to that format. `C0000` is not actually a valid warning message number in MSVC.)

In the case of GCC / clang, it's simply using the supported pragma for displaying a warning message using `_Pragma()` instead of `#pragma` or `#warning`.

Comment: Your `EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_STRINGIFY0()`, `EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_STRINGIFY1()`, and `WARNING()` macros are identical in both branches of the `#ifdef` so why not move them outside to avoid duplication? The only thing needing the `#ifdef` is your `EMIT_COMPILER_WARNING_COMPOSE()` macro.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point!

Answer (score 0):

`#warning` is not a standard C99 feature (because some compilers only support C99, and some programs may not be compiled with C++11 and later standard libraries), so it cannot be used on compilers that do not support it. You can use `#ifdef` to check the defined compiler and change the directive based on the compiler.
Easiest (but not the best) solution:

```cpp
#ifdef _MSC_VER  // if MSVC is the compiler
#    pragma NOTE(warning: warning here)
#else            // implied GCC or CLang
#    warning(warning here)
#endif
```

MSVC uses `#pragma` instead of `#warning`

Comment: Nitpicking: Why do you refer to C99 if the OP asks for C++11?