# Endianess macros not correctly defined

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, clang

I'm trying to compile `grpc`, and one of the targets uses `/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h` which contains this :

```
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
        uint8_t th_x2:4;        /* (unused) */
        uint8_t th_off:4;       /* data offset */
# endif
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
        uint8_t th_off:4;       /* data offset */
        uint8_t th_x2:4;        /* (unused) */
# endif
```

Somehow, the two conditions are fulfilled which makes the compilation fail (`error: duplicate member 'th_off'`). I wrote a test C program and it seems that the three macros are not correctly defined.

I tried to reinstall `gcc` and `g++`, and also downgrade them to a previous version. I also tried to reinstall the Linux headers. I finally tried to compile with `clang`, but it doesn't work either.

My two test computers are running Ubuntu 19.10 and the result is the same on both of them. Is there a compiler flag or a system configuration needed to define these macros?

EDIT : `tcp.h` is a system header. I did not write it and it's an almost fresh install of Ubuntu with a standard installation of `build-essentials`.

EDIT 2 : I used a test program and it works correctly in this case. It shows `little`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int main() {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    std::cout << "little\n";
#endif
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    std::cout << "big\n";
#endif
}
```

Comment: `__LITTLE_ENDIAN` and `__BIG_ENDIAN` are two different constants, so they can't both be equal.  Somewhere in the source they have been redefined.

Comment: @stark He's saying they're not defined at all, so the preprocessor is treating them all as `0`.

Comment: What do you get if you `printf("BE: %d\nLE: %d\nBO: %d\n", __BIG_ENDIAN, __LITTLE_ENDIAN, __BYTE_ORDER)`

Comment: I see these two constants in /usr/include/endian.h

Comment: @stark I see them defined in `/usr/include/endian.h`. `bits/endian.h` just defines `__BYTE_ORDER` to one of them.

Comment: Yeah - I was looking on Cygwin.  On Ubuntu they're in /usr/include/endian.h

Comment: Please add your test program to your question.

Comment: In which source file of `grpc` is this happening?

Comment: You can of course simply define the macros appropriately  in your makefile or even on top of your includes in the sources, potentially evaluating the other possibilities as well. Admittedly that is very unsatisfying. There is also a [header file online](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/tcp.h) which says "#error "Adjust your <asm/byteorder.h> defines" if the expected defines aren't there, indicating that this is not uncommon.

Comment: @user3684240 grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc

Comment: And the system header code you post is leaving me wanting from a code quality standpoint. One should test for #ifdef, and if that seems to cumbesome, one can always use [function-like macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33760158/3150802) which don't compile if undefined, instead of silently and wrongly resolving to 0.

Comment: I added the test program result in my question

Comment: Perhaps you are using a different compiler than the one whose system headers are not in `/usr/include` ?   It would be rather poor if this grpc explicitly lists that parth to include.

Comment: Re "*I used a test program and it works correctly in this case.*", Please provide the minimal case where it *doesn't* work.

Comment: @ikegami The problem with `grpc` is that it's a massive project. It may be hard to figure out how to create a mcve. I just compiled it and was sort of hoping to get the same problem - but all compiled just fine.

Comment: @loics2 When you built, did you add any configuration or did you just do `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make`?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Re "*The problem with grpc is that it's a massive project.*", Right, and the OP didn't identify the steps they took; they didn't pare down the program to a compilation unit; nothing. "I'm trying to compile grpc" is not a suitable demonstration of a problem, *especially* for something as large as this.

Comment: @ikegami Perhaps not. The file `grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc` was mentioned, but only in a comment.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yep, just that

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian system, `__LITTLE_ENDIAN` and `__BIG_ENDIAN` are defined in `/usr/include/endian.h`. I believe this file is intended to be generic across architectures.

`__BYTE_ORDER` is defined to be one of them in `/usr/include/bits/endian.h`. I think the `bits` directory contains headers that are specific to a particular architecture.

`tcp.h` includes `<types.h>`, which I think should indirectly include these and define the macros. I'm not sure why it's not happening for you.

Comment: On my system here, `netinet/tcp.h` includes `sys/types.h`, and the only include to `endian.h` I see in there is if `__USE_BSD` is defined

Comment: On my Ubuntu 19.10 machine, `<endian.h>` is included if `__USE_MISC` is defined.  However if `__USE_MISC` is not defined then `<netinet/tcp.h>` never attempts to declare the offending struct in the first place.

Comment: Same here, almost the entire header is inside `#ifdef __USE_MISC`.

Comment: Likely something is redefining feature test macros (or the glibc-internal proxies for them like `__USE_MISC`) after the first standard header is included, causing inconsistencies in what is exposed. For example if `<sys/types.h>` were already included with FTMs that don't expose `<endian.h>`, then later the macros were changed before `<netinet/tcp.h>` was included, the endian macros would be missing, as OP saw.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the gcc builtins:

```
# if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
        uint8_t th_x2:4;        /* (unused) */
        uint8_t th_off:4;       /* data offset */
# endif
# if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
        uint8_t th_off:4;       /* data offset */
        uint8_t th_x2:4;        /* (unused) */
# endif
```

In the c preprocessor, two macros which do not exist are equal.

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: Why would a system header file have the wrong macros? BTW, I just checked my Debian system, it's the same as in the question.

Comment: Those are the gcc builtins, not the header file constants

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: As @Barmar says, I did not edit the file, it comes like this...

Comment: @walnut true!. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27054190/3150802) is relevant which attempts to list all "known" macros but actually it is also incomplete (but at least catches that). What a mess.

Comment: Weird. I edited the answer to use the gcc builtin names.

Comment: "_You could use the gcc builtins_" - Note that this is a system header file. Changing a system header file is usually not a good idea.

Comment: I have seen some definitions in libc which use `elif` and the little endian first, perhaps to avoid exactly this mess?

Comment: @user3684240 OP does not have that option. It's a system header file.