# Memory Mapping for AUTOSAR

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, embedded, autosar

i am new in AUTOSAR and embedded system
my project defined variable along with memmap as part autosar standard as below

```
#define ABC_START_SEC_VAR_CLEARED_BOOLEAN
#include "abc_MemMap.h"
   boolean var1_b;   
   boolean var2_b;        
#define ABC_STOP_SEC_VAR_CLEARED_BOOLEAN
#include "abc_MemMap.h"
```

-> var1_b and var2_b will be arrange into specific memory
so if someone did the mistake as below

```
boolean var1_b;   
boolean var2_b;
```

they forgot include ABC_START_SEC_VAR_CLEARED_BOOLEAN and STOP and when i do the build -> NO ERROR happen
so what do you think about this point ?

where will var1 and var2 be arrange in Memory ?
and do u have any way to detect this point because the build is pass and compiler cant recognize this ERROR

thank you

Comment: If you don't use the macros or include the header file, all you have are two normal C variable definitions. There's no way for a standard compiler to detect that these shouldn't be normal global (I assume) variables.

Comment: Can you not use the [assert](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_assert.htm) macro?  ( i.e. `assert (var1_b == FALSE)` ).  If you are more concerned with _does the variable exist_ then [this may help](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/59173-how-check-if-variable-exists.html).

Comment: do u know how to know those variables are in normal or special memory ?

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the variable properly, as per AUTOSAR. You can find the variable declaration prototype from the AUTOSAR Compiler Abstraction Specification document.

As per AUTOSAR, your variable declaration should be like below:

```
#define ABC_START_SEC_VAR_CLEARED_BOOLEAN
#include "abc_MemMap.h"
VAR(boolean, ABC_VAR_CLEARED) var1_b;
VAR(boolean, ABC_VAR_CLEARED) var2_b;
#define ABC_STOP_SEC_VAR_CLEARED_BOOLEAN
#include "abc_MemMap.h"
```

You have to add the ABC_VAR_CLEARED memory class into linker file and, once you've done your compilation process, `var1_b` and `var2_b` will be allocated under  the ABC_VAR_CLEARED section in the map file.

Answer (score 0):

This is general problem for the Memory mapping in Autosar stack development.

> **Where will var1 and var2 be arrange in Memory ? :**

It will be dummped into unmapped and uninitialize memory section usually `non-bss or .data` section. Based on your Microcontroller based memory alignment and Memory section size allocated in linker file, var1 and var2 will laydown on adjacent memory location. Best way to know where var1 and var2 located go to `<project>.map` generated after your compilation and you can find mapping section and addresses.
To know more about memory type use this [LINK](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller)

> **Do u have any way to detect this point ?:**

I presume that current memory mapping is done in `memmap.h` in your project in which you are doing the Section mapping with tags like `#define ABC_START_SEC_VAR_CLEARED_BOOLEAN`
Solution which I prefer is to have `#ifdef` condition under your `memmap.h` file.
In this way at last of this `memmap.h` you will had `#else` condition you can introduce `#error` and its message and can create compilation error.
You can see the syntax in this [Pre-Processor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221517/how-do-i-generate-an-error-or-warning-in-the-c-preprocessor) question.

There is one drawback in solution mentioned above i.e.
This condition method do not indicate which mapping section has a problem but indicates one more sections are mis-mapped and then owner need to check manually where mis-mapping happened.